# how to get the normal name of audio devices

Tags: android, linphone, linphone-sdk

I use the linphone sdk and i want to get a list of audio devices, or rather their type and driverName, but it outputs in the style of {2: Audio, 3: Audio, 1: AAudio}
Although if you do this on ios, it gives out normally in the style of {3: Speaker}

And here I would also like to do it on android

code:

```
val devices = core.audioDevices
val devicesMap: Map<Int, String> = devices.associateBy({ it.type.ordinal }, { it.driverName })
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do not know about linphone sdk but there is an Api in android named AudioDeviceInfo and it has methods that would satisfy you requirements.

```
    AudioManager audioManager = (AudioManager) getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
        AudioDeviceInfo[] devices = audioManager.getDevices(AudioManager.GET_DEVICES_OUTPUTS);
        for (AudioDeviceInfo device : devices) {
            Log.d("Type",device.getType()); 
            Log.d("Product Name",device.getProductName());
            
        }
```

- getType method will return an int value which associated with the
  type constant [list of constants](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/AudioDeviceInfo#getType())
- [getProductName()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/AudioDeviceInfo#getProductName()) will return the human-readable name of the audio device in a CharSequence.

Comment: I tried to get it this way and everything was output in the same style, for example, {2: M2006C3MNG} will be output from your code like this

Comment: 2 is the constant value for TYPE_BUILTIN_SPEAKER and that string is the name of speaker provided by android, you can go through the list of constants in the docs

Comment: you can have a long when block in to map each of the int values to their type